# How to enable/disable auto brightness mode from API

Tags: android, brightness

I want to control the system settings "auto brightness", setting it ON or OFF. I'm able to control the brightness level but only if AUTO is OFF. From what I read until now there is a SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE in Settings.System but only for API level 8 or higher and also not recommended to mess wit it. But currently my phone has Android 2.1 (API 7) and there are widgets that can control this setting (enable/disable auto brightness and set the level). How is this done?

Answer (score 3):

I solved my problem using:

```
private static final String SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE = "screen_brightness_mode";
private static final int SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL = 0;
private static final int SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_AUTOMATIC = 1; 

Settings.System.putInt(resolver, SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, mode); 
Settings.System.putInt(resolver, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, lev);
```

This works in API versions 7 and 8, not sure about earlier versions.

Comment: sorry for the n00b question - but can you tell me exactly what the 'mode' parameter is? I've been trying to get this code to work by assigning the mode var to either 0 or 1 but to no effect... no compile or runtime errors - just doesn't do anything...

Answer (score 1):

I guess this should work for you:

```
Settings.System.putInt(resolver, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, mode); 
Settings.System.putInt(resolver, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, lev);
```

And remember to add permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```