# how to get the status of automatic brightness is ON or OFF in settings programmatically in android

Tags: android

i created the toglle button for automatic brightness setting changed.here i want to know about the automatic brightness is ON or OFF state if it is on state the togglebutton will be off ,if it is on toggle button will be off ,how to do here

please help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable/disable auto brightness mode from API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957749/how-to-enable-disable-auto-brightness-mode-from-api)

Comment: the answer to this question is also acceptable..

Answer (score 4):

```
int brightnessmode;

getBrightMode();

if(brightnessmode==1){
//below code will off the auto mode

                android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(contentresolver, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE,
                        Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL);

//Here perform any action you want
}

if(brightnessmode==0){
//below code will on the auto mode

                android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(contentresolver, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE,
                        Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_AUTOMATIC);
//Here perform any action you want
}

//This method will give brightness mode
//if brigthnessmode=0 means Auto mode is currently off
//if brightnessmode=1 means Auto mode is currently on
protected void getBrightMode() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        brightnessmode = System.getInt(contentresolver, System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("tag", e.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_AUTOMATIC);
```

using SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE mode
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to read this from the [Settings.System](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html), look for SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE